# send_mail is working while EmailMultiAlternatives.send is not

Tags: python, django, django-email

I am finding this very odd. This piece of code doesn't send two email messages. The first way using send_mail is working find. While using EmailMultiAlternatives isn't sending any messages. I've already debugged user.email, and it is using failed email addresses, in case of the obvious.
This code runs from a management command.

```
send_mail("test", "test", "test@test.com", ["my@email.com"])                                                                    
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
             self.TITLE,
             self.generate_text_content(cans, cants, "week"),
             settings.NOREPLY_EMAIL, [user.email])
msg.attach_alternative(self.generate_html_content(cans, cants, "week")
                    ,"text/html")
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: That's the strangest thing. No errors, not even with fail_silentfly=False.

Comment: Isn't there any `try...except` wrapping it? What does `msg.send()` return?

Comment: Not even catching an exception. Guess I should contact my hosting provider.

Comment: I am having the same issue please help me if you solved the problem

Comment: @FightWithCode can you check if `user.email` is None or not?

Comment: How have you set up `smtp` connection? @JonasGeiregat

Comment: what is your email backend? check `settings.EMAIL_BACKEND`